# Convert (Int, String) to String to print array

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am trying to call an array to be printed in a table view. The only problem is the array (numbersWithCreationDate)is of type `[(Int,String)]`. How can I get numbersWithCreationDates to work here. So the text can be printed. Its saying this is not working because it can only take a string.

```
   cell.textLabel?.text = numbersWithCreationDates[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of the array that is of type `int, String`.

Comment: Does this help     var numbersWithCreationDates = [(Int,String)]()

Comment: So you have an an array of tuples. You should edit your question to state that clearly, and put the code from your comment right into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Get the tuple:

```
// Get the tupel at index of the current row
let tupel = numbersWithCreationDates[indexPath.row]
```

Get the string:

```
// Get the second value of the tupel, the string value ...
let string = tupel.1
cell.textLabel?.text = string
```

Comment: error message coming states cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(int, String)'

Comment: Updated answer  accordingly.

Comment: Will this get all of the entries in the array. It being tuple.1

Comment: If you return `numbersWithCreationDates.cout` in `numberOfRowsInSection`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into a String data type.

Try this:

`cell.textLabel?.text = String(numbersWithCreationDates[indexPath.row])`

Explanation:

`UITableViewCell` consists of `UILabel`. The `text` property of `UILabel` expects a `String` whereas you are passing a `Number`(or `Int`). When you call `String` initializer, it converts this `Number` to `String` which is expected by `text` property of `UILabel`.

Comment: error message coming states cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(int, String)'

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use part of the tuple, or you want to format it a certain way, you can separate the parts using `.0` and `.1`.  For example:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Number: \(numbersWithCreationDates[indexPath.row].0) Date: 
\(numbersWithCreationDates[indexPath.row].1)"
```